# Convert string to json in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
json.loads('{"name": "Sam"}')
{u'name': u'Sam'}
```

Should this not show

`{"name": "Sam"}` ?

Python 2.7

What is the issue?

Comment: It was decoded as Unicode strings. This is not an issue. A better question might be: "How can I *force non-unicode output* from `json.loads`?" (And, really, one probably should just move along..)

Comment: Those are unicode strings. It's basically the same. search for u'' python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your title betrays some confusion, it says "converting strings to JSON". You aren't *converting to JSON*, you are *deserializing a string encoded in the JSON format* into a Python object.

Second, you ask:

> Should this not show
>
> `{"name": "Sam"}` ?

No, it shouldn't. Those would imply Python 2 `str` types, which are byte-strings. The [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) is very clear:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
>   double quotes, using backslash escapes.

So the Python `json` parser is correctly returning the `unicode` data-type, which in Python 2, will have it's representation pre-fixed with a `u`. Note that isn't *part of the string*, it is part of its *representation*.

Note, in Python 3 (which you should probably be using anyway), the `str` type corresponds to Python 2 `unicode` type, with the old byte-strings belonging to the `bytes` class. If the `u`s really bother you, then switch to Python 3 :)

So, in conclusion, there is no issue. According to the JSON standard, json strings are unicode strings, and the Python `json` parser deserialized to the unicode datatype in Python 2. This is expected, desirable, and well-documented behavior.

Comment: Since JSON is the *serialized representation*, it's not strictly a "requirement" that implementations map to Unicode for in-program values.. but such is an edge-case and it would be even more odd to have Unicode and "clean" ASCII string types coming back.. many languages (including Python 3) have dropped the notion of non-Unicode string (fsvo Unicode).